# Programmitacally generate multiple beans

Tags: spring, spring-bean

I have multiple merchants and a WSDL with different configurations is needed for each merchant. Right now, I'm copying and pasting the following method and changing the configs. But it creates some difficulties (requires code change & deployment). I want to initialize it programmatically at the run time. I've [tried these](https://medium.com/@venkivenki4b6/spring-dynamically-register-beans-in-4-ways-at-run-time-c1dc45dcbeb9) methods but it din't work.
Is it possible?

```
@Bean(name = "marchant-1")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema commonSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("Marchant1WSPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/Marchant1WebService");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://.../");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(commonSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved similar kind of problem by specifying scope of my bean as `prototype`. Below example explains my implementation:

Create your `DefaultWsdl11Definition` class as shown below:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Getter
@Setter
public class DefaultWsdl11Definition {
    private String portTypeName;
    private String locationUri;
    private String targetNamespace;
    private XsdSchema schema;
}
```

Implement `ApplicationContextAware` to generate `beans` programmatically:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ApplicationContextAwareImpl implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ApplicationContextAwareImpl.initApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    }

    private static void initApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ApplicationContextAwareImpl.context = applicationContext;
    }

    /**
     * @param requiredType Bean class
     *
     * @return Bean of required type
     */
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) {
        return context.getBean(requiredType);
    }
}
```

Use `ApplicationContextAwareImpl.getBean()` method to generate beans programmatically:

```
DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = ApplicationContextAwareImpl.getBean(DefaultWsdl11Definition.class);

wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("Marchant1WSPort");
wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/Marchant1WebService");
wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://.../");
wsdl11Definition.setSchema(commonSchema);
```

---

Also you can make use of `Qualifier` and `Bean` annotations to generate multiple beans of same type:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfigurations {
    @Qualifier("marchant-1")
    @Bean(name = "marchant-1")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition1(XsdSchema commonSchema) {
            DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
            wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("Marchant1WSPort");
            wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/Marchant1WebService");
            wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://.../");
            wsdl11Definition.setSchema(commonSchema);

            return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Qualifier("marchant-2")
    @Bean(name = "marchant-2")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition2(XsdSchema commonSchema) {
            DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
            wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("Marchant2WSPort");
            wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/Marchant2WebService");
            wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://.../");
            wsdl11Definition.setSchema(commonSchema);

            return wsdl11Definition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
@Configuration
public class WsBeanLoader implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        SimpleXsdSchema xsd = new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/sample.xsd"));
        xsd.afterPropertiesSet();
         BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = builder(name, xsd);
         registry.registerBeanDefinition(name, builder.getBeanDefinition());
    }

    private BeanDefinitionBuilder builder(String name, SimpleXsdSchema xsd) {
        name = StringUtils.capitalize(name);
        BeanDefinitionBuilder builder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(DefaultWsdl11Definition.class);
        builder.addPropertyValue("serviceName", name + "WebService");
        builder.addPropertyValue("portTypeName", name + "WSPortBinding");
        builder.addPropertyValue("locationUri", "/WS/" + name + "WS");
        builder.addPropertyValue("targetNamespace", "url..");
        builder.addPropertyValue("schema", xsd);
        return builder;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

    }
}
```